# How to use the same function twice in different elements?

Tags: jquery, row

I have created a table that you can add rows to with multiple input fields, however I need two tables. and i can't get the second one to work. I checked the console and no errors and I have tried copying it and changing the identifiers however that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
        id: "addr"+newid,
        "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);

        var children = cur_td.children();

        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });

            var c =   $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
            c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
            c.appendTo($(td));
            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });

    // add delete button and td
    /*
    $("<td></td>").append(
        $("<button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>")
            .click(function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            })
    ).appendTo($(tr));
    */

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
 });

// Sortable Code
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
};

$(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified      
}).disableSelection();

$(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();



$("#add_row").trigger("click");
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bg208a17/)

Comment: Can you make fiddle for  this?

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bg208a17/

Comment: what you have tried to achieve ?? where do you get failed in code?

Comment: the code works fine. I just need two of the same thing, I tried copying and changing the identifiers but the second one didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to go through all the html and make all the adjustments but will offer guidance on how to make it work.

First... since ID's can't be repeated in page you need to switch out ID's for classes.

Next you need to start at the main container element that wraps every part of this whole module. All the selectors used need to be based on looking in from this main container so they are only specific to each module instance.

You do this by using traverses like `find()` and `closest()` quite a bit .

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table tab-logic"></table>
  <a class="add-button">
</div>
```

As with writing a jQuery plugin, wrap all the code within an `each` that loops the outer module containers. This loop helps us insulate the instances

```
var $containers = $('.table-responsive').each(function(){
     // assign variables for instance specific components

      // cache instance of this container so we don't do numerous searches for it in DOM
     var $cont = $(this),
         //there is only one table within this container         
         $table =$cont.find('table'),
         $rows = $table.children();

         // start adding events and use our cached instance collections from above
       var  $addBtn  = $cont.find('.add-button').click(function(){
            $rows.each(....

             .....
             // we know this is the instance specific table already
             $table.append(...
         });     


});
```

This guideline should help you make the conversion. These patterns are very common in repeating elements and you will find yourself using them a lot.

By using this approach it would also be trivial to convert the whole thing to a plugin later on if you found a need for it

Comment: I know the id's can't be repeated, I tried changing them in the second table, but no success.

Comment: Make the selectors match in both. Should be literally able to make it work in one table...then copy paste another duplicate table into page

Comment: You are still using ID selectors... that was priority one to switch out all the ID's for classes in the html and in the jQuery selectors

Comment: What is new link for? Take out the second table. Go through every selector that uses ID selector and make sure it is insulated within the container and that the class matches in html

Comment: Because selectors like `$(".add_row").on("click"` will find all of that class in page. Pay attention to the part i wrote about everything must be referenced from the outer container. I even showed how to do the button for you

Comment: Yes, i'm just having trouble with the implementation of that.

Comment: Have you use `find()` before? or closest()? If you haven't used them look them up in the api and get familiar with exaamples there. You have to be able to see the dom as a tree....and you are at the trunk looking down 2 different branches...nd if you are at the end of the branch you want to reach back just to the trunk and no further

Comment: i have used closest, but not find. looking at it now. https://jsfiddle.net/bg208a17/6/

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with the DOM, i'm just not sure how to call the right table on click if they both have the same class name. i'm seeing .find is obviously useful. but again implementation is not going so well.

Comment: Inside the outer each `this` is the instance container. I showed you how to isolate table already. That's why I set `var $table=$(this).find('table')` which represents only one table

Comment: so var $table=$(this).find('table', 'table2') - would find two tables?

Comment: why would you need that ? There is only one table inside each module container

Comment: yeah, mate I wouldn't have ask the damn question if i knew how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

make two function : one for adding row, one for deleting row

run function for 1 or 2 times depends on how many rows you want.

in deleting row you should check for minimum rows allowed in this way you'll be able to delete row index 1 also,

currently row 1 is fixed

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was asking. I need 2 tables, not two rows.